# What is a correct overpass-turbo query for getting all streets in a city?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want to get all streets in NYC using http://overpass-turbo.eu/. I tried this:

```
[out:json]; area[name = "New York"]; (node(area)[highway=street]; ); out;
```

However it returns

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.55.1009 5e627b63",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2019-11-13T19:26:03Z",
    "timestamp_areas_base": "2019-11-13T18:05:02Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [



  ]
}
```

No elements. However this query:

```
[out:json]; area[name = "New York"]; ( node(area)[amenity=cinema]; node(area)[highway=street]; ); out;
```

for getting streets *and* cinemas, works:

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.55.1009 5e627b63",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2019-11-13T19:29:02Z",
    "timestamp_areas_base": "2019-11-13T18:05:02Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 344994897,
  "lat": 41.7680892,
  "lon": -73.9291000,
  "tags": {
    "amenity": "cinema",
    "created_by": "Potlatch 0.10f",
    "name": "Roosevelt Theater"
  }
},
...
```

How should I modify the initial query to get the streets?

Comment: crosspost: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341746/what-is-a-correct-overpass-turbo-query-for-getting-all-streets-in-a-city

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two errors in your query.

### Error 1: highway=street

Where does this [tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) come from? `street` is not a valid value for the [`highway` key](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway). In fact, since you want to obtain *all* streets you have to omit the value completely and just query for `highway`.

### Error 2: node()

A road is not a [node](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) but a [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way). So you have to query for `way(area)[...]` instead. This also requires a recurse-up step (`>;`) to retrieve all nodes of these ways.

### Corrected query

```
[out:json]; area[name = "New York"]; (way(area)[highway]; ); (._;>;); out;
```